# Existence of non-trivial solutions for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to prove the following claim:

For a square matrix $A$ there exists a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Ax=0$ if and only if $A$ is singular.

Is this claim correct?

I was able to show that if $x$ exists, $A$ is singular.

How to prove right-to-left part? (i.e, if $A$ is singular, there is a non-zero $x$ s.t. $Ax=0$).

**UPD:**

I'm assuming the following definition:

Matrix $A$ is *singular* if it is not invertible. (i.e, there does not exist matrix $B$ s.t. $AB=BA=I$(indentity matrix)).

I also know that $A$ is singular iff $det(A)=0$

Comment: this claim is correct!

Comment: (singularity-theory) refers to something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $A$ is singular. This means that for some $x \ne y$ we have $Ax = Ay$ (otherwise, see what $A$ does to a vector space basis and you'll see that it would have to be nonsingular).

What can you say about $A(x - y)$?

Comment: I can only prove by contradiction that if we are given $Ax=Ay$ for some $x \neq y$, $A$ is singular. It do not see how it implies that for each singular $A$ such $x$ and $y$ must exist.

Answer (score 1):

this claim is correct! If A is singular, then the column vectors of A are not linearly independent. (They are linearly dependent). 
 
If $A = [\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2},\dots \vec{u_n}]$, 
$\exists$ $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{F}$, ($\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R} \text{ or } \mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$) probably in your case 
  such that not all of the $\alpha_i$ are zero:
$$
\vec{u_1}\alpha_1 + \vec{u_2}\alpha_2+\dots + \vec{u_n} \alpha_n =\vec{0}
$$

So take your vector: $\vec{x}$ to be $\vec{x}$:= $[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots \alpha_n]^{T}$

Comment: Why the column vectors of A are not linearly independent? It sounds as hard to prove to  me as the original claim.

Comment: @Evgenii.Balai I think that is occasionally taken as the definition of a singular. For your above comment, $A$ being singular means $A$ is not injective(otherwise you could "undo" the function), so there are $x \neq y$ such that $Ax=Ay$. I guess you should be more clear about what you are assuming and explain your current knowledge so you can get good/useful answers.

Comment: @PaulPlummer I'm  assuming that $A$ is singular iff it is not invertible. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ singular $\iff \det(A)=0$. The characteristic polynom of $A$ is $\det(A-\lambda I)$, so iff $\det(A)=0$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then by definition $\ker(A)\neq\{0\}$.